# VRP: detection of variables with empty domains possible?

Tags: or-tools

I had a "bug" in my vehicle routing problem. I assigned stop 1 to vehicle 0 and vehicle 1. Can such infeasibilities be detected / reported?

Example Code Python:

```
cpsolver = routing_model.solver()
cpsolver.Add(routing_model.VehicleVar(1) == 1)
cpsolver.Add(routing_model.VehicleVar(1) == 0)
```

Results in solver status:

> ROUTING_FAIL: No solution found to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is reported. 
The model is inspected only upon loading, which is done at the beginning of the solve.

Comment: Where and how is it reported? By "reporting" I imagined something like "empty domain: node 1 can not be assigned to any vehicle, check your constraints!"

Comment: Your case is trivial. But finding a minimal set explanation for failure is a very hard problem. We do not have a good solution for this.